# jQuery datepicker css validation to W3C standards

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker, w3c-validation

I am trying to get the W3C Validator working for all my XHTML and CSS.  However, when using the standard jQuery datepicker, I get 23 CSS validation errors in the `jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.css` file that came with the download.

I really don't want to have to change my footer (or add a non-standard footer) to remove the CSS validation icon, but I also don't want to customize the CSS file to eliminate these errors either.  Are these the only two options I have?

Comment: just out of curiousity the errors aren't from the images that jquery ui css automatically tries to load?

Comment: No @ScottSelby, it seems to be a lot of radius doesn't exist for webkit, khtml, and moz ( e.g., `Property -webkit-border-top-left-radius doesn't exist : 4px`).  Also, opacity errors, `Property zoom doesn't exist : 1` and a few other errors.

Comment: I would try to download the jquery ui css again , I googled it , and it does not look like a common problem , I haven't used w3c validation before , but unless you really like the custom design in that custom css , try to download again from jquery.com @Sable

Comment: The `-webkit-XXX`, `-moz-XXX`, etc. properties are there for compatibility with older browsers. If you remove them, you'll reduce the warnings, but you'll reduce compatibility.

Comment: I just tried it; a fresh download from http://jqueryui.com/download/ gives the identical filename.  I just kept the defaults, (which was everything selected), and have the same error messages.

Comment: @Barmar, the two problems with this is maintenance (remembering to change the standard UI css file) and it also doesn't eliminate all of the issues, so I still can't claim compatibility.    This question is really more a focus on a major tool (jQuery) not being "out of the box" W3C compliant.  It makes me wonder about validation... even google gets 24 errors when entering the URI into the HTML validator, and 4 CSS errors in the CSS validator.

Comment: In this case the option is either going for compliance and having it not work in older browsers, or not being compliant and having it work in as many browsers as possible. Is it an absolute requirement to be able to say it passes the W3C validator? That to me seems less important than having the datepicker work on older browsers.

Comment: I doubt that meeting validation standards is a major focus of the jQuery development. One of the reasons to use libraries like jQuery is because they try to handle all the quirks of different browsers, so you don't have to worry about them. They don't restrict themselves to just the core W3C standards, they do whatever is necessary to implement the functions.

Comment: I'm surprised that `-mox-XXX` properties produce errors rather than warnings. The CSS specification specifically states that properties beginning with "-" or "_" are reserved for browser-specific extensions.

Comment: @Barmar, it does produce errors, not warnings; I don't know the standards well enough to comment.  The website works well, but I like to have the W3C logo to help build trust and add perceived value to the site.

Answer (score 2):

For zoom property - its a fix for IE. Commonly used by jQuery or Google. So if the zoom is your only bug - dont bother with it :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't be overzealous with the validator. It only provides you with quick overview of the potential problems you may have. Having browsers' prefixes on your CSS doesn't affect your page loading or browser performance by any mean. It won't rank your site higher if your CSS pass all the rules. Today front-end development is in continuous change. Drafts are changing everyday and new features are experimented. If you want your CSS 100% to be valid then remove all the prefixed rules ... It comes with a price though.